# How can i find variable in view file codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

view :

```
<table class="table table-hover">
                  <tr>

                    <th>Heading</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                  </tr>
                  <?php foreach ($result as $row) { ?>
                  <tr>


                    <td><?php echo $row->heading_name ;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->description_name; ?></td>

                  </tr>
                  <?php } ?>
 </table>
```

Model:

```
function view_description(){
        $this->db->order_by("id","DESC");
        $query = $this->db->get("description_update");
        return $query->result();
   }
```

controller:

```
public function update_heading(){
        $config = array(
            array(
                'field' =>'heading_name', 
                'label' =>'Name',
                'rules' => 'trim|required'
            ),
            array(
                'field' => 'description_name',
                'label' => 'Description',
                'rules' => 'trim|required'
            )
        );

        $this->form_validation->set_rules($config);
        if ($this->form_validation->run()== FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('modules/admin/general.php');
        }
        else{
            $data = array(
            'heading_name'  => $this->input->post('heading_name'),
            'description_name' => $this->input->post('description_name')
            );

            $this->description_model->add_description($data);

            $data['message'] = 'Data inserted Successfully';
            $this->load->view('modules/admin/general.php',$data);
        }
        $data['result']= $this->description_model->view_description();
        $this->load->view('modules/admin/general.php',$data);
        // print_r($data);


    }
```

I want to view result data in my view file but it says result variable not found but in same code when $result data showing the result in another view file.
I don't know what need to do.
Note: I am new in CodeIgniter

TIA

Answer (score 0):

No need to load this view in 29 lines as your aim is to load result data.

$this->load->view('modules/admin/general.php',$data);

Comment: removed it but same issue Message: Undefined variable: result

Answer (score 0):

Try placing `$data['result']` at top of code like and in the false part of form add the `$data` as well

Also when loading views you do not need `.php`

`$this->load->view('modules/admin/general', $data);`

Function

```
public function update_heading(){

    $config = array(
        array(
            'field' =>'heading_name', 
            'label' =>'Name',
            'rules' => 'trim|required'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'description_name',
            'label' => 'Description',
            'rules' => 'trim|required'
            )
    );


    $this->form_validation->set_rules($config);

    $data['message'] = '';

    // $data['result'] = array();

    $data['result'] = $this->description_model->view_description();

    if ($this->form_validation->run()== FALSE) {

        $this->load->view('modules/admin/general', $data);

    } else {

        $data = array(
            'heading_name'  => $this->input->post('heading_name'),
            'description_name' => $this->input->post('description_name')
        );

        $this->description_model->add_description($data);

        $data['message'] = 'Data inserted Successfully';

        $this->load->view('modules/admin/general',$data);
    }
}
```

Comment: This error message showing continuously Message: Undefined variable: result